# how do i make this into a dropdown menu using html, css and scss

Tags: html, css, sass, drop-down-menu, navbar

I am trying to make a dropdown menu using html, css and scss.

help would be appreciated.

```
 <nav>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="nav-logo">
      <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="/img/logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="search-container">
      <div class="fa fa-search search-icon"></div>
      <div class="input-container"><input type="text" placeholder="search"></div>
      <div class="fa fa-times cross"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-boxes">
      <ul>
        <div class="nav-link-boxes">
          <li class="links"><a href="home.html">home</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-link-boxes">
          <li class="links"><a href="catalog.html">catalog</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-link-boxes dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <div class="links"><a href="paintings.html">portfolio</a></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <div class="nav-link-boxes dropdown-links">
            <li>embroidery</li>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-link-boxes dropdown-links">
            <li>vector</li>
          </div>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <div class="nav-link-boxes">
          <li class="links"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <img class="login" src="./img/accounticon.svg" alt="login">
  </div>
</nav>
```

sass file

```
@import "var";
.nav {
  &-container {
    z-index: 1;
    background: $navbar-gradient;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    width: 95%;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 4rem;
    height: 6rem;
    left: 1.1rem;

    .search-container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      text-align: center;
      background: $search;
      padding: 1rem;
      border-radius: 2rem;
      /* box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgb(255, 249, 238); */

      input {
        display: flex;
        margin: auto auto;
        margin-left: 1rem;
        // /* width:500px; */
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        background: $search;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;

        ::placeholder {
          color: $placeholder;
        }
      }
    }

    .nav-boxes {
      ul .boxes {
        display: flex;
        margin-right: 2rem;
        margin-left: 2rem;
        align-items: center;
        list-style-type: none;
        a {
          font-family: "Exo 2", sans-serif;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 1.4rem;
          color: $dark-primary;
          font-weight: 600;
          &:link,
          &:visited {
            border-radius: 2rem;
            transition: all 0.9s;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    .links {
      margin: 0 0.4rem;
    }

    .nav-link-boxes {
      padding: 0.5rem;
      margin-right: 0.7rem;
      background-color: $nav-buttons;
      border-radius: 3rem;
      padding-bottom: 0.8rem;

      &:hover {
        transform: translateY(-0.3rem);
        box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem $white;
      }
      &:active {
        transform: translateY(-0.1rem);
        box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }
    }

    .login {
      height: 9rem;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  }

  &-logo {
    padding: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    .logo {
      height: 5.2rem;
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to make a portfolio website and i am creating a navbar and inside the navbar there is dropdown menu in the portfolio tab. i have wrapped a div around each list item, so i can apply styles and i cant wrap a div around the whole list item otherwise all the list items in the nested list get contained in it.

i am using sass and there seems to be issue with specificity and some things dont work and i dont know how to nest them, but ultimately i want to create dropdown menu.

Comment: Your HTML as posted is invalid a div cannot be a direct child of ul `<ul>
        <div`

Answer (score 0):

The proper HTML element for a drop-down is [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select). So instead of `<ul class="dropdown">`, write:

```html
<select>
  <option value="embroidery">embroidery</option>
  <option value="vector">vector</option>
</select>
```

You can then style your select element however you like. For example:

```css
select {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Other_form_controls#drop-down_controls) you can find good examples of how drop-down controls can be approached.

Comment: i managed to fix it. thank you